# How to "unfollow" people on ResearchGate

Tags: researchgate

How do I unfollow people on ResearchGate, to avoid receiving information that is irrelevant to me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On your profile page in the area where the people your are following is located, click on "View all" and then a pop-up will give you the option to unfollow people.

**Edit: more details from support:**

You can unfollow a ResearchGate user by following these steps:
- when viewing your own user profile in ResearchGate, click on the 'View all' link above the list of people you follow at the bottom right.
- in this list, locate the person you wish to 'unfollow'. If you scroll your mouse over the grey 'Following' box on the right of their name this box will change to an 'Unfollow' link.

Alternatively, visit the user’s profile page, and click the unfollow link in the menu at the bottom right of the ‘Info’ tab.

Comment: Thanks, was just not obvious on 1st attempt

Comment: Will the person that I'll Unfollow receive a notification telling him that I am no longer following him?